# how to import CSV table with header containing spaces

Tags: tables, csv, csvsimple

The header column names in my CSV contain spaces. Is there a way to still import it using `csvsimple` or maybe some other package? That way I would be able to specify data in CSV, import it and render it automatically as a **table** via a package. Additionally, since the headers are long, I'd like the table to expand up to page width and wrap long headers.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{forum_posts_table_1.csv}
    posts per author,sentences per post,quoted sentences per post,EREs per post,mentions per ERE
    3.1,23.83454,2313.27,13453453.8,2464642.43
\end{filecontents*}
```

Comment: What do you mean "import"?  How do you intend to use the data?  I am thinking the `readarray` package can help.  I could try to compose an answer, if I could understand how you want the data to be digested and recalled.

Comment: p.s.  If you choose `readarray`, make sure you employ the latest version (2.0), dated `2016/11/07`

Comment: as Steven said, would do you want to do? `pgfplotstable` can also read this file without problems.

Comment: For example, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}[2016-11-07]
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{forum_posts_table_1.csv}
    posts per author,sentences per post,quoted sentences per post,EREs per post,mentions per ERE
    3.1,23.83454,2313.27,13453453.8,2464642.43
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\readdef{forum_posts_table_1.csv}\mydata
\readarray*\mydata\myarray[-,\ncols]
Column 3 title is ``\myarray[1,3]''.\par
Column 3 data is ``\myarray[2,3]''
\end{document}`

Comment: It all depends on how you intend to use the data. All the named packages may be helpful (including `csvsimple`). Spaces inside the header are no problem as far as you do not make automated macros with `head to column names`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I want to import it and render it as a **table** with the help of a package. `csvsimple` does that, but I can't figure out how to deal with headers and spaces.

Comment: Are the numbers of rows and columns unknown in advance?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, unknown. I'd like to keep the usage generic. `csvsimple` does everything I need except CSV headers with spaces. However, even in `csvsimple` I need to specify which columns to render. In that sense the column number is known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have written in my comment, all depends on how to use the data. `csvsimple` has no problem with spaces inside the header as far as you do not create automated macros with `head to column names`.

An example usage is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,array,filecontents,booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{forum_posts_table_1.csv}
    posts per author,sentences per post,quoted sentences per post,EREs per post,mentions per ERE
    3.1,23.83454,2313.27,13453453.8,2464642.43
    4.1,23.83454,2313.27,13453453.8,2464642.43
    5.1,23.83454,2313.27,13453453.8,2464642.43
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\myhead[1]{\parbox[t]{5em}{\centering\bfseries#1\par\kern1mm}}

\csvreader[no head,column count=5,tabular=rrrrr,
  table head=\toprule,
  late after first line=\\\midrule,
  table foot=\bottomrule
  ]%
{forum_posts_table_1.csv}{}{%
  \csviffirstrow{\myhead{\csvcoli} & \myhead{\csvcolii} & \myhead{\csvcoliii}
    & \myhead{\csvcoliv} & \myhead{\csvcolv}
    }{\csvlinetotablerow}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Newbie question: what do expressions surrounded with `]%` and `{%` signify?

Comment: The `%` deletes the linebreak which would insert a blank space otherwise. It may be not needed everywhere in the the above.

Comment: If you say `column count=5`, why can't `csvsimple` just load the first 5 columns by default? I mean the columns of the header as well, the way you've written it.

Comment: @m33lky  The option `column count=5` is needed for `\csvlinetotablerow`. You could omit it and replace `\csvlinetotablerow` by `\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv`.

Comment: What if the data for a particular column is very long. How can I force csvsimple to softwrap the content?

Comment: @m33lky It's all a matter of the tabular settings. `tabular=p{5cm}rrrr` for example would create a first column with 5cm width which wraps the content.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I'm really struggling with my csv file as well, [any help will be appreciated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430726/csvsimple-table-going-off-of-page)!

Answer (score 4):

The great `datatool` package seems to have no problem with spaces in headers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\DTLloadrawdb{posts}{forum_posts_table_1.csv}
\renewcommand{\dtlheaderformat}[1]{\parbox[t]{5em}{\bfseries
    #1}}
\DTLdisplaydb{posts}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To improve this answer, can you give an example of its use?

Comment: Datatool has great documentation, but if you insist...