# Latex for-loop for table header generation

Tags: tables, loops, csvsimple

In the table given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358776/42852) there is repetition of the columns. Is there a way to loop over them in Latex, so that you don't have to manually write out the columns? That way the table would just load the first 5 columns without the user typing such things as `\myhead{\csvcoliv}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,array,filecontents,booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{forum_posts_table_1.csv}
    posts per author,sentences per post,quoted sentences per post,EREs per post,mentions per ERE
    3.1,23.83454,2313.27,13453453.8,2464642.43
    4.1,23.83454,2313.27,13453453.8,2464642.43
    5.1,23.83454,2313.27,13453453.8,2464642.43
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\myhead[1]{\parbox[t]{5em}{\centering\bfseries#1\par\kern1mm}}

\csvreader[no head,column count=5,tabular=rrrrr,
  table head=\toprule,
  late after first line=\\\midrule,
  table foot=\bottomrule
  ]%
{forum_posts_table_1.csv}{}{%
  \csviffirstrow{\myhead{\csvcoli} & \myhead{\csvcolii} & \myhead{\csvcoliii}
    & \myhead{\csvcoliv} & \myhead{\csvcolv}
    }{\csvlinetotablerow}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For-loops are used in TeX with the commands `\loop` and `\repeat`. Just set an if-statement in front of the `\repeat`: `\loop\StuffToBeDone\ifagain\repeat` with `\StuffToBeDone` the stuff you want to be done in each repetition and `\ifagain` an if-statement which evaluates to false if the loop should end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fiddling for a while, I came up with a solution (not using a `\loop`-`\repeat`-solution):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,array,filecontents,booktabs}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcount\loopcount
\loopcount=5
\newcounter{loopiti}

\def\continuefortheglory{%
    &\fortheglory%
}

\def\fortheglory{%
    \stepcounter{loopiti}%
    \myhead{%
        \expandafter\csname csvcol\roman{loopiti}\endcsname%
    }%
    \ifnum\loopcount>\value{loopiti}%
    \expandafter\continuefortheglory%
    \fi%
}


\begin{filecontents*}{forum_posts_table_1.csv}
    posts per author,sentences per post,quoted sentences per post,EREs per post,mentions per ERE
    3.1,23.83454,2313.27,13453453.8,2464642.43
    4.1,23.83454,2313.27,13453453.8,2464642.43
    5.1,23.83454,2313.27,13453453.8,2464642.43
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\myhead[1]{\parbox[t]{5em}{\centering\bfseries#1\par\kern1mm}}

\csvreader[no head,column count=5,tabular=rrrrr,
  table head=\toprule,
  late after first line=\\\midrule,
  table foot=\bottomrule
  ]%
{forum_posts_table_1.csv}{}{%
  \csviffirstrow{\myhead{\csvcoli} & \myhead{\csvcolii} & \myhead{\csvcoliii}
    & \myhead{\csvcoliv} & \myhead{\csvcolv}
    }{\csvlinetotablerow}
}

\vskip5mm
using fortheglory:
\vskip5mm

\setcounter{loopiti}{0}
\csvreader[no head,column count=5,tabular=rrrrr,
  table head=\toprule,
  late after first line=\\\midrule,
  table foot=\bottomrule
  ]%
{forum_posts_table_1.csv}{}{%
    \csviffirstrow{\fortheglory}{\csvlinetotablerow}
}


\end{document}
```

[image: results]

EDIT: With this you have to use `\loopcount=` for every table, that doesn't have the same number of columns as the previous one and have to issue `\setcounter{loopiti}{0}` before every table, but you could include this in a wrapper command like this:

```
\newcommand{\glorycol}[1]{\loopcount=#1\setcounter{loopiti}{0}\fortheglory}
```

Then you just have to use it for a table with, e.g. 5 columns, like this:

```
\csvreader[no head,column count=5,tabular=rrrrr,
  table head=\toprule,
  late after first line=\\\midrule,
  table foot=\bottomrule
  ]%
{forum_posts_table_1.csv}{}{%
    \csviffirstrow{\glorycol{5}}{\csvlinetotablerow}
}
```

There might be a better way (for example automaticly determining the number of columns and giving an optional argument just if that fails) but that's out of my skill (at the moment, I hope...).

Comment: I have to say that for-loop constructs are not that well-integrated in TeX as compared to JavaScript+HTML.

Comment: @m33lky Using for-loops in TeX is not that hard. Problems arise when you want to use them with stuff like `&` in between (same is true for `\if...\fi`, making the second `\expandafter` prior to the `\continue...`in my code necessary). If this answer is satisfying to your needs, you might accept it, if not feel free to ask stuff.

Comment: In your solution you have to manually define the counter `loopcount` for every table to be imported this way, right?

Comment: @m33lky please see my edit. (And sorry for weird names of counters and commands)