# csvsimple table going off of page

Tags: tables, csvsimple

I have the following CSV `dow_distribution.csv` file:

```
dow,ANZ Volume,BHP Volume,CBA Volume,MQG Volume,NAB Volume,QAN Volume,RHC Volume,TLS Volume,WBC Volume,WOW Volume,AORD Volume,Total Volume
Monday,3.63,6.64,1.93,0.88,3.14,5.77,0.23,19.89,3.56,1.57,457.56,504.81
Tuesday,4.11,7.74,2.12,0.92,3.64,7.04,0.25,22.3,4.07,1.8,520.05,574.05
Wednesday,4.36,8.14,2.26,1.02,3.86,7.58,0.26,23.82,4.3,1.91,543.45,600.96
Thursday,4.56,8.32,2.46,1.07,4.22,7.3,0.25,24.05,4.44,2.05,547.04,605.76
Friday,2.47,4.61,1.36,0.63,2.22,3.76,0.13,13.38,2.33,1.02,292.65,324.58
Saturday,,,,,,,,,,,,0
Sunday,1.58,2.88,0.86,0.35,1.4,2.46,0.09,8.91,1.56,0.76,194.2,215.06
```

I want to process this into a table that fits onto the width of my page.

I've tried below - and have been reading the [csvsimple package](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf) to rectify it but having difficulty doing so.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}      %  Commented out due to Cautionary error. 
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\begin{document}

\csvautotabular{dow_distribution.csv}

\end{document}
```

**Current Output:**
[image]

**Desired Output:**

Perhaps having a line break between the ticket names and the "Volume" might help shorten the width of the table (did it with MS paint), :
[image]

If it doesn't all fit in one go, I would like it look like:
[image]

Comment: Hi. Did you find a way to make the table split like in your last picture? Thank you

Comment: @Confounded I didn't need to do that, Thomas F. Sturm solution worked very well for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\csvautotabular` macro is just for quick visualization. It it not intended to be used for productive code. Here, `\csvreader` or `\csvloop` allow customization.

I have two suggestions for your table.

The first one sets the table columns to a fixed width of `9mm` which results in breaking the title automatically.

The second one rotates the long title texts by 90 degrees with help of the `graphicx` package and a small auxiliary macro `\myrot`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}      %  Commented out due to Cautionary error.
\usepackage{csvsimple,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\def\myrot#1{\rotatebox{90}{\csname csvcol#1\endcsname\ }}

\begin{document}

{\small\tabcolsep1.4mm%
\csvreader[
  tabular=|r|*{12}{p{9mm}}|,
  nohead,column count=13,
  table head=\hline,
  late after first line=\\\hline,
  table foot=\hline]{dow_distribution.csv}%
{}%
{\csvlinetotablerow}
}

\bigskip

\csvreader[
  tabular=|r|*{12}{c}|,
  nohead,column count=13,
  table head=\hline,
  late after first line=\\\hline,
  table foot=\hline]{dow_distribution.csv}%
{}%
{\csviffirstrow{%
  \csvcoli & \myrot{ii} & \myrot{iii} & \myrot{iv} & \myrot{v} & \myrot{vi} & \myrot{vii}
  & \myrot{viii} & \myrot{ix} & \myrot{x} & \myrot{xi} & \myrot{xii} & \myrot{xiii}
}{\csvlinetotablerow}}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]